# Is there a way to teleport someone somewhere after they have died (x) amount of times?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I play this custom game called SUPER CRAFT BROS and in this custom game we have 3 stock lives.

I usually teleport everyone manually after 3 deaths. There are, however, people who cheat and lie.

Is there any way to have them teleported back to spawn after 3 deaths?

Comment: Which version do you use? The minecraft tag is for the java edition, the minecraft-console tag is for the console edition.

Comment: I use Xbox version but sometimes I use pc

Comment: So this particular question is about the xbox version?

Comment: Are you asking if this can be done automatically or if there's any way for you to know if the "cheaters and liars" are being sincere or not?

Comment: I want to know if there’s a way for it to Ben automatic like I type in a command that’s but Needs Redstone and then I flip the lever and everyone gets 3 lives and when they lose them they get teleported to set coordinates

Comment: Like ik how to do the teleporting but I don’t know how to give them 3 lives unless I give them a scoreboard of 3 deaths and I descend and have it test for 0 lives and teleport them if they have 0 but i just don’t know the commands

Comment: Flagging question as unclear as there is not enough information in the question to know which edition it pertains to.

Comment: "Like ik how to do the teleporting" leads me to believe that this *is* Java, unless they are talking about host privileges' teleport to player which i somewhat doubt

Answer (score 3):

If this is for the Legacy Console Edition, I don't think this is possible as scoreboards aren't available.

However, if this is for the Java Edition this is easily done with the `deathCount` scoreboard criterion.

### Step 1: Create scoreboard objective

Run this command:

```
scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount
```

This adds a scoreboard objective called "deaths" that increments when a player dies.

### Step 2: Teleport players when they die 3 times

Add this command to a repeating, unconditional, always active command block:

```
execute as @a[scores={deaths=3}] run tp @s X Y Z
```

where `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are the coordinates you want to teleport the people who've died to. This would continually run the command `tp @s X Y Z` as all the players who have their `deaths` objective set to 3.

### Step 3: Stop teleporting the players once they've been teleported

The above repeating command block would also mean that players are continually being teleported, meaning that they cannot move. There are two ways I can think of right now, which will only work if the area where you're teleporting the players to can't be accessed by the players who haven't died 3 times (sorry, I don't play on Java and I don't know that many commands).

#### Method 1: Reset the death counter

Add this command to a repeating, unconditional, always active command block:

```
execute @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,dx=1,dy=2,dz=1] run scoreboard players set @a[scores={deaths=3}] deaths 0
```

This will set the deaths of all players at `X`, `Y`, `Z` to 0.

#### Method 2: Use tags

This is if you don't want to reset the counter.

Add the following command to yet another repeating, unconditional, always active command block:

```
execute as @a[scores={deaths=3}] run add tag needsToBeTeleported
```

This will add the tag `needsToBeTeleported` (or whatever you want to call it) to all players who have died 3 times.

Then, go back to the commmand block in step 2 and change it to this:

```
execute as @a[tag=needsToBeTeleported] run tp @s X Y Z
```

This will teleport all players with the tag `needsToBeTeleported` to `X`, `Y`, `Z`.

Finally, add another repeating, unconditional, always active command block with the command:

```
execute @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,dx=1,dy=2,dz=1] run tag @s remove needsToBeTeleported
```

This would remove the tag `needsToBeTeleported` from all players at `X`, `Y`, `Z`.

---

Also, make sure that all the repeating command blocks are in a loaded chunk by placing them in the spawn chunk, using the [`forceload`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/forceload) command, or by simply placing them in an area you know someone is going to be in all the time.

If you don't want command block stuff in chat like `Teleported <player> to <x>, <y>, <z>` you can run `gamerule commandBlockOutput false`.

---

Disclaimer: I only play BE so I actually haven't tested any of this out, but it should work.